# Parse.js + AngularJS app relational data query issue

Tags: parsing, angularjs, parse.js

I have two parse classes; Companies and Ratings. It is a one to many relationship. Companies can have many Ratings. This is the statement I would perform in SQL:

```sql
SELECT Companies.name, Ratings.rating
FROM Companies
INNER JOIN Ratings
ON Ratings.name_id = Companies.name_id
ORDER BY Companies.name
```

I want the equivalent of this in Parse, but I'm not sure of how to go about it. Here is what I've currently tried:

```js
function getRatings() {
  var tableA = new Parse.Query(Companies);
  var tableB = new Parse.Query(Ratings);

  tableB.equalTo("name_id", tableA.name_id);
  tableB.find({
    success: function(results) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.companies = results.map(function(obj) {
          return {
            id: obj.get("name_id"), 
            name: obj.get(tableA.name), 
            rating: obj.get("rating"), 
            parseObject: obj
          };
        });
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
}
```

I am calling this function when the controller loads. This code displays the rating in my output, but not the name of the company.

I am trying to get all the companies listed in the companies object, then pair them with all the ratings they have in the ratings object. Their common key is `name_id`. This is the code I am using within my Angular view:

```html
<div class="span12">
    <div ng-repeat="company in companies | filter: query | orderBy: orderList" 
         class="well company-description">
        <h1>{{company.name}}</h1>
        <h3>Rating: {{company.rating}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I am way off base on this, please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `name_id` column in the `Ratings` class. This isn't how you're supposed to define relationship using Parse.

There are a couple of options for you to choose.

**Option 1**

Using the Parse data browser, add a new column under the `Companies` class, called `ratings`. It should be a column of type `Relation` and point to `Ratings` as the target class. (Let me know if you need more information on how to do this.)

Then, when you create or edit a company, add ratings as follows:

```
var Companies = Parse.Object.extend("Companies");
var Ratings = Parse.Object.extend("Ratings");

var company = new Companies({name: "Some Company"});
company.relation("ratings").add(new Ratings({stars: 5}));
company.save();
```

Then, when querying `Companies`, do so as follows:

```
new Parse.Query(Companies).find({
    success: function(companies) {
        for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
            companies[i].relation("ratings").query().find({
                success: function(ratings) {
                    // Finally, I have the ratings for this company
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Option 2**

Using the Parse data browser, add a new column under the `Companies` class, called `ratings`. It should be a column of type `Array`.

Then, when you create or edit a company, add ratings as follows:

```
var Companies = Parse.Object.extend("Companies");
var Ratings = Parse.Object.extend("Ratings");

var company = new Companies({
    name: "Some Company",
    ratings: [new Ratings({stars: 5})]
});
company.save();
```

Then, when querying `Companies`, do so as follows:

```
new Parse.Query(Companies).include("ratings").find({
    success: function(companies) {
        // Yay, I have access to ratings via companies[0].get("ratings")
    }
});
```

`include("ratings")` tells Parse to include the actual objects, rather than pointers to objects for the given key.

**Conclusion**

Option 1 is better if you are expecting to have a large amount of ratings for each company, and if you don't always plan on retrieving all the ratings each time you query the companies.

Option 2 is better if the number of ratings for each company is relatively small, and you always want ratings to come back when you query companies.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your post, it makes a lot more sense now the way you have described it. However, I've been trying the second option you listed here, but I seem to be getting back incorrect results. It is returning the entire ratings object, and my rating is being output like this: '[{"stars":5,"objectId":"V2NZoe64G2","createdAt":"2013-03-08T18:54:05.372Z","updatedAt":"2013-03-08T18:54:05.372Z"}]' using ratings.stars returns me undefined.

Comment: So you only want the `stars` property, instead of the entire `ratings` object?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure. I don't exactly understand what is going on here. I think the `ratings` for that company are being added to the `ratings` object correct? What I want to do eventually is retrieve the average rating... add all the `stars` up, divide by total amount of `ratings`.

Comment: I've been trying to get Option 1 running. However, whenever I create a rating manually in the browser, the relation doesn't seem to save correctly. It saves in in the Ratings object, but when I View Relation it does not appear. And when I try to use the code for Option 1 to create an object, I receive the following error in the console: `Uncaught You can't add an unsaved Parse.Object to a relation. `

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to resolve the `Uncaught You can't add an unsaved Parse.Object to a relation.` error.

```
    var addRating = new Ratings({stars: rating}); // save rating first, then associate it with a company
    addRating.save({
        success: function() {
            var addCompany = new Companies({name: name});
            addCompany.relation("ratings").add(addRating);
            addCompany.save();
        }
    });
```

The rating has to be saved first, then the company relation can be added later on... makes sense, but took me awhile to figure it out! :S

Comment: Good to know! Have you run into a lot of headaches with angular and parse.com? I'm asking because I'm currently comparing BaaS options.